# Migrated VPN server broken with macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, vpn, server.app, catalina

My Mac mini has been working just fine with macOS Mojave as a VPN server following the migration method described in the [macOS Server Service Migration Guide](https://developer.apple.com/support/downloads/macOS-Server-Service-Migration-Guide.pdf), but after upgrading to macOS Catalina there is trouble.

The VPN clients connect just fine on the internal network, but not on an external network; which makes the VPN server a bit pointless!

I can confirm that all was working well with the server running macOS Mojave, and my iOS 13 and iPadOS 13 clients have been connecting just fine; it is the upgrade to macOS Catalina on the server that has caused this problem.

Here are the log entries for a failed connection:

```
2019-10-12 20:42:38 CDT Incoming call... Address given to client = 10.0.0.224  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : Directory Services Authentication plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : Directory Services Authorization plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : L2TP incoming call in progress from 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx'...  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : L2TP received SCCRQ  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : L2TP sent SCCRP  
2019-10-12 20:42:38 CDT Incoming call... Address given to client = 10.0.0.225  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : Directory Services Authentication plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : Directory Services Authorization plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : L2TP incoming call in progress from 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx'...  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : L2TP received SCCRQ  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:38 2019 : L2TP sent SCCRP  
2019-10-12 20:42:40 CDT Incoming call... Address given to client = 10.0.0.226  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:40 2019 : Directory Services Authentication plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:40 2019 : Directory Services Authorization plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:40 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:40 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:40 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:40 2019 : L2TP incoming call in progress from 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx'...  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:40 2019 : L2TP received SCCRQ  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:40 2019 : L2TP sent SCCRP  
2019-10-12 20:42:44 CDT Incoming call... Address given to client = 10.0.0.227  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:44 2019 : Directory Services Authentication plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:44 2019 : Directory Services Authorization plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:44 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:44 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:44 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:44 2019 : L2TP incoming call in progress from 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx'...  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:44 2019 : L2TP received SCCRQ  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:44 2019 : L2TP sent SCCRP  
2019-10-12 20:42:48 CDT Incoming call... Address given to client = 10.0.0.228  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:48 2019 : Directory Services Authentication plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:48 2019 : Directory Services Authorization plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:48 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:48 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:48 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:48 2019 : L2TP incoming call in progress from 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx'...  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:48 2019 : L2TP received SCCRQ  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:48 2019 : L2TP sent SCCRP  
2019-10-12 20:42:52 CDT Incoming call... Address given to client = 10.0.0.229  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:52 2019 : Directory Services Authentication plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:52 2019 : Directory Services Authorization plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:52 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:52 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:52 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:52 2019 : L2TP incoming call in progress from 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx'...  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:52 2019 : L2TP received SCCRQ  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:52 2019 : L2TP sent SCCRP  
2019-10-12 20:42:56 CDT Incoming call... Address given to client = 10.0.0.230  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:56 2019 : Directory Services Authentication plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:56 2019 : Directory Services Authorization plugin initialized  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:56 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:56 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:56 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:56 2019 : L2TP incoming call in progress from 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx'...  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:56 2019 : L2TP received SCCRQ  
Sat Oct 12 20:42:56 2019 : L2TP sent SCCRP  
2019-10-12 20:42:58 CDT    --> Client with address = 10.0.0.224 has hung-up  
2019-10-12 20:42:58 CDT    --> Client with address = 10.0.0.225 has hung-up  
2019-10-12 20:43:00 CDT    --> Client with address = 10.0.0.226 has hung-up  
2019-10-12 20:43:04 CDT    --> Client with address = 10.0.0.227 has hung-up  
2019-10-12 20:43:08 CDT    --> Client with address = 10.0.0.228 has hung-up  
2019-10-12 20:43:12 CDT    --> Client with address = 10.0.0.229 has hung-up  
2019-10-12 20:43:16 CDT    --> Client with address = 10.0.0.230 has hung-up
```

I’m currently using the built-in VPN on macOS Catalina 10.15.1

Comment: Can you edit in the bottom of the page the version of server.app and the `sw_vers` on the server in question?

Comment: What does the log look like on the VPN client? It is possible that the client is not receiving the SCCRP due to a NAT or firewall issue, but it seems more likely it is rejecting the SCCRP for some reason.

Comment: Exact same client, exact same router and firewall. Only difference is the server running Catalina vice Mojave.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250730386

Comment: I understand it is the exact same client and server and firewall. You have posted the log from the VPN server. What I am asking for is the log from the VPN client.

Comment: Ok, how would I go about getting that from an iphone? Also I reverted the server back to Mojave and changed nothing else and the vpn is working again.

Comment: If you connect your iPhone or iPad to a macOS computer and open Console.app (/Applications/Utilities/Console.app), you should see the device in the Sources list (you may need to open the sources list from View/View Sources). If you then filter on "ppp" or "racoon" you can see VPN related traffic.

Comment: Also need to see the client VPN settings and cipher preferences...

Comment: Common problem, per the thread OP posted.   (And one person reports a rarely working workaround.)

Answer (score 1):

The migration guide isn't well-designed:  A lot of folks would likely miss this section.

> The following services **require users whose password type is
> RECOVERABLE**: 
> • **VPN** 
> • RADIUS  
> If macOS Server is installed and configured, you can use it
> to create additional users whose password type can be set to
> RECOVERABLE.  
> NOTE: If Server app is removed, you will no longer be
> able to create users whose password type is RECOVERABLE

Comment: @user3344646, did you give up?  (Good advice from Peltzer above, too.)

Comment: I tried all this and nothing. I had server installed and the account was set with the password recoverable.

Comment: Ah well. I thought I'd stumbled on the answer.  I guess it will be for some.  (I  presume you meant password TYPE recoverable.  You didn't respond to Peltzer.)